# QTextEdit and saving images to .html

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I get images from QTextEdit for saving them in .html files with `<image>`?

Usual `QTextEdit.ToHtml()` doesn't work.

Comment: be sure to add some code you tried. That shows effort.

Answer (score 0):

Hence the label `pyqt` not defining it should be pyqt5 (I'll ignore the `pyqt5` label due to the fact you did not show effort by posting code you tried. Therefore you need modify the script yourself accordingly to fit it for use with pyqt5).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class TextView(QtGui.QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self,Ui_MainWindow, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setAcceptRichText(True)

    def insert(self, string,emoticonList):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        if not emoticonList:
            cursor.insertText(string)
        else:
            ls = shlex.split(str(string))
            for word in ls:
                for emoticon in emoticonList[:]: 
                    if word == emoticon:
                        path = "image/emoticons/" + word
                        icon = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
                        image = icon.toImage()
                        cursor.insertImage(image)
                    else:
                        cursor.insertText(word + " ")
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)
        end = "<br>"
        fragment = QtGui.QTextDocumentFragment.fromHtml(end)
        self.textCursor().insertFragment(fragment)

    def insertReceiveMessage(self, msg):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.insertText(msg)
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)
        end = "<br>"
        fragment = QtGui.QTextDocumentFragment.fromHtml(end)
        self.textCursor().insertFragment(fragment)
```

Original code can be found [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22495-How-to-display-image-on-QPlainTextEdit).